# how to safely bypass Delphi Error: "types of formal and actual parameters must be identical"

Tags: delphi

I need a way to write a generic procedure to act upon an object type or any of its descendants.

My first attempt was to declare

```
procedure TotalDestroy(var obj:TMyObject);
```

but when using it with a descendant object

```
type TMyNewerObject = class(TMyObject);
var someNewerObject: TMyNewerObject;

TotalDestroy(someNewerObject);
```

I get the infamous error "types of formal and actual parameters must be identical"

So, while strugling to find a solution, I looked at the source code of Delphi system `FreeAndNil` procedure. And I found this awesome declaration, along with this astonishing comment

```
{ FreeAndNil frees the given TObject instance and 
  sets the variable reference to nil.  
  Be careful to only pass TObjects to this routine. }

procedure FreeAndNil(var Obj);
```

It avoids the type checking error, but it uses no safety net.

My question is ... is there any safe way to check the type of an untyped var parameter?

or in other words, can you improve this Delphi source code so that the warning would not be needed?

```
procedure FreeAndNil(var Obj);
var
  Temp: TObject;
begin
  Temp := TObject(Obj);
  Pointer(Obj) := nil;
  Temp.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Don't you think that procedure would've been written differently if there was a way to do it?

Comment: I don't know, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: PA, the answer to Lasse's question is *yes*. If there *were* a better way, then the library function would have used it. Since the library function *doesn't* use it, we can safely conclude that there is no better way.

Comment: @Rob: "safely conclude"? Are you saying the Delphi team is infallible? As much as I like Delphi, I don't buy *that*. :-)

Comment: Of course not, Ulrich. The non-type-safeness of `FreeAndNil` is well known, it's acknowledged to be a wart, as caveats in the code comments suggest. If there were a way to fix it, it would have been fixed. It hasn't, so there isn't.

Comment: I'd think that would be a case of "If it ain't broke, don't fix it."

Comment: I think that's a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denying_the_antecedent fallacy, what you mean is 'If there was a way to fix it that the Delphi team had thought of and if they had time to fix it, and it was of a higher priority than other known errors in the system, they would have fixed it', so it's not quite a safe conclusion.

Comment: Zartog, Ulrich's last comment implies that the reason for not fixing `FreeAndNil` is that it's not broken. There could of course be *other* reasons for not fixing it, such as what you list, but that's not what Ulrich said. My comment served to refute Ulrich's reasoning — the reason for not fixing `FreeAndNil` cannot be that it's not broken because it *is* broken. Ulrich was **not giving a conditional premise** — if he were, then "don't fix it" would need to be something we could assign a truth value to. But it's not. He was giving an instruction. The antecedent-denial fallacy doesn't apply.

Comment: I wasn't referring to Ulrich's comment, I was referring to your first comment.

Comment: Oh. In that case, it's not denying the antecedent at all. Here was my argument: If there were a way to resolve the problem of `FreeAndNil` lacking type-safety, then it would have been fixed (P → Q). The procedure is still *not* type-safe (¬Q). Therefore, there is not yet any way to make `FreeAndNil` type-safe (∴¬P). I was denying the **consequent**, not the **antecedent**, and that's a perfectly sound logical technique.

Comment: Those logical fallacies always make my head hurt. :-) What I meant was: FreeAndNil works for a lot of people since a lot of years, so the people who have to decide over a rewrite might consider it not broken enough to justify the costs of a rewrite - e.g. maybe breaking some obscure code somewhere out there. But enough  hairsplitting: I too don't think there's a better way to write FreeAndNil with current Delphi.

Comment: While writing my last sentence regarding current Delphis an idea occurred to me: Maybe you can make a generic out of TotalDestroy? Maybe even an inlined one-liner just calling a cast-ridden InternalTotalDestroy? Unfortunately I have no D2009/10 around to check.

Comment: @UliGerhardt "*I too don't think there's a better way to write FreeAndNil with current Delphi*" - there is with modern Delphi, and it has [actually been done now in Delphi 10.4 Sydney](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/New_features_and_customer_reported_issues_fixed_in_RAD_Studio_10.4). The new implementation is still not perfect, but it is better than it was before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've written about this before, using an example very similar to [Lasse's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051673/how-to-safely-bypass-delphi-error-types-of-formal-and-actual-parameters-must-be/2051769#2051769):

- [Delphi Q&A: Why must the types of actual and formal var parameters be identical?](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/var-identical)

Unless you're writing an assignment statement to *change the value* of the input parameter itself, and not just one of its properties, you shouldn't pass a parameter by reference in the first place.

If you *are* writing an assignment statement to change the parameter's value, then the compiler message really is true, and you should heed it.

One reason for needing to by-pass the error is when you're writing a function like [`TApplication.CreateForm`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Forms.TApplication.CreateForm). Its job is to change the input parameter's value, and the type of the new value varies and cannot be determined at compile time. If you're writing such a function, then your only option with Delphi is to use an [*untyped var*](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/untyped) parameter, and then there is extra burden on both the caller and the receiver to make sure everything goes right. The caller needs to make sure it passes a variable that is capable of holding values of whatever type the function will put in it, and the function needs to make sure it stores a value of a type compatible with what the caller requested.

In the case of `CreateForm`, the caller passes in a class-reference literal and a variable of that class type. The function instantiates the class and stores the reference in the variable.

I don't think very highly of either `CreateForm` or `FreeAndNil`, largely because of the way their untyped parameters sacrifice type safety in return for comparatively little extra convenience. You haven't shown the implementation of your `TotalDestroy` function, but I suspect its var parameter will ultimately provide the same low utility as in those other two functions. See my articles on both:

- [When should I use `FreeAndNil`?](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/freeandnil)
- [Why shouldn't I call `Application.CreateForm`?](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/createform)

Comment: As you cleverly guessed, my TotalDestroy does some special clean up of TMyObject and finally does a FreeAndNil.

Comment: If there's special cleanup required for a `TMyObject`, consider putting that in the destructor. Don't force consumers of your class to learn a new way of destroying it when plain old `Free` works fine for everything else.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I take your point, I don't need my TotalDestroy. I will go just with my Destroy destructor I already have. And let the user decide if they want it thru FreeAndNil or not.

Answer (score 11):

Let's examine what you want to do.

You want to call a method that takes X, passing in an object of type Y, where Y is a descendant of X. The snag, the parameter is a "var" parameter.

Let's analyze what you could do if that was possible.

```
type
    TBase = class
    end;
    TDescendant = class(TBase)
    end;

procedure Fiddle(var x: TBase);
begin
    x := TDescendant.Create;
end;

type
    TOtherDescendant = class(TBase)
    end;

var a: TOtherDescendant;
a := TOtherDescendant.Create;
Fiddle(a);
```

Uh-oh, now `a` no longer contains an instance of `TOtherDescendant`, it contains an instance of `TDescendant`. That probably comes as a surprise to the code that follows the call.

You must not only consider what you *intend* to do with the syntax you propose, but effectively what you *could* do with the syntax.

You should read Eric Lipperts excellent blog post about similar issues in .NET, found here: [Why do ref and out parameters not allow type variation?](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/09/21/why-do-ref-and-out-parameters-not-allow-type-variation.aspx).

Comment: thanks for your insight and for the link. As I commented below, my intention is to finally nil the reference.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what Lasse wrote, which is quite correct, most of the time you don't want to pass an object to a **var** parameter anyway.

An object is a reference type.  What you see as the object is actually a reference to it.  You would only want to pass an object *reference* to a **var** parameter if you wanted to change your object out for a new object.  If you just want to be able to modify the members of the object, then you can do that by simply passing it to a normal parameter.  Make method call take a `TMyObject` parameter instead of a `var TMyObject` parameter and it should work.

Of course, if you really are replacing the object, then feel free to disregard all this, and see Lasse's answer.

Comment: Agreed, I didn't think of that angle. Quite correct, you don't need "var" if all you want is the reference.

Comment: in fact, I just wanted to nil it, performing some special clean up first.

Answer (score 1):

> can you improve this Delphi source code so that the warning would not be needed?

Yes, you can get a type safe way to avoid the compiler error.
In the newest Delphi 10.4 Sidney, the `FreeAndNil` procedure has been changed into this:

```
procedure FreeAndNil(const [ref] Obj: TObject);
var
  Temp: TObject;
begin
  Temp := Obj;
  TObject(Pointer(@Obj)^) := nil;
  Temp.Free;
end;
```

It is type safe for objects and will catch errors when passing an interface reference for example.

The way to pass a parameter by `const [ref]` means that the parameter is passed by reference. Without the [ref] attribute, parameters with size equal and smaller than a pointer would otherwise be passed by value.

Here, even though the object is passed as a constant, the reference will be modified.
In that sense, it is not a perfect declaration, but will do its job better than the former implementation.

From [New features in Delphi 10.4](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/New_features_and_customer_reported_issues_fixed_in_RAD_Studio_10.4#FreeAndNil):

> This means that incorrect usage of FreeAndNil will now cause a compiler error. In the past, incorrect usage would not be caught, leading to difficult bugs. Note that although the parameter is declared as const, the by-reference variable is indeed modified.
>
> A new, but ‘not as bad’, class of incorrect calling is possible with this declaration of FreeAndNil: the method can be called passing in properties or a method result, as well as cast expressions, a type’s implicit conversion to TObject, etc. The nil-ed value will then be the temporary variable in the expression.