# Why Delphi compiler can't see I'm trying to free an interface?

Tags: delphi, interface, crash, free, delphi-xe

I've done a small mistake while coding this week-end.
In the following code, I'm creating an object and cast it to an **interface**. Later, I'm trying to **free it** with `FreeAndNil()`;

```
type
  IMyIntf = interface
     [...]
  end;

  TMyClass = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyIntf)
     [...]
  end;

var
  Myintf : IMyIntf;
begin
  Myintf := TMyClass.Create;
  [...] // Some process
  FreeAndNil(Myintf); // CRASH !!!
end;
```

Of course, the program crash at this line.
I **totally understand the issue**, but what I don't understand is **why the compiler doesn't warn me about it** ?  There is no dynamic things behind, it's just that I'm trying to free an interface !!! Why don't it write me an error / warning ?

Is there any real explanation behind or is it just a compiler limitation ?

Comment: Computers do what you tell them to do, not what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Seth When I'm coding GET_THE_THINGS_DONE(), it doesn't do what I'm telling ... :)

Comment: Actually, crash happens one line below what you stated. Anyway, compiler cant see because it have no eyes. http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51QR-B9n6lL._SL500_AA300_.jpg

Comment: @TridenT I bet it would call `GET_THE_THINGS_DONE`, which is what you told it to do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you know, the correct way to do this is to write `Myintf := nil`, or just to let it go out of scope. The question you ask is why the compiler accepts `FreeAndNil(Myintf)` and does not complain at compile time.

The declaration of `FreeAndNil` is

```
procedure FreeAndNil(var Obj);
```

This is an untyped parameter. Consequently it will accept anything. You passed an interface, but you could have passed an integer, a string and so on.

Why did the designers choose an untyped parameter? Well, they needed to use a `var` parameter since the whole purpose of `FreeAndNil` is to free the object **and** set the object reference to `nil`. That can't be done by a method of the target object and so a `var` parameter of a standalone function is needed.

You might imagine that you could write

```
procedure FreeAndNil(var Obj: TObject);
```

since all objects are descended from `TObject`. But this does not do the job. The reason being that the object you pass to a `var` parameters must be exactly the type of that parameter.  If `FreeAndNil` was declared this way you would have to cast to `TObject` every time you called it.

So, the designers decided that the best solution to the design problem, the least bad choice, is to use the untyped var parameter.

Comment: @TridenT That is correct. In order to be able to do my day job I wrote a HeffBot that does my stack overflow work for me....   ;-)

Comment: You could argue that the better solution would have been to fix the language so that a "var" param of some object type would accept references to an object to that type or any type derived from it.  I have a hazy memory of someone once trying to explain how this would be A Bad Thing, but the rationale escapes me right now.  :)

Comment: @Deltics I'm playing this one with a straight bat. Given the constraints imposed by the language, this was probably the best compromise available.

Comment: If you were allowed to pass a variable typed as a descendant of the declared var parameter type, then you could possibly assign an instance of the *wrong* type! Consider this:

type
  TFoo = class(TObject)
  end;
  
  TBar = class(TObject)
  end;

procedure SetInstance(var Inst: TObject);
begin
  Inst := TFoo.Create;
end;

var
  O: TBar;
begin
  SetInstance(O);
end.

Comment: @Deltics: It might be my article on covariance and generics that you're thinking of? ( http://tech.turbu-rpg.com/149/generics-and-the-covariance-problem ) It uses the basic rationale Allen gave, and outlines a possible solution which would require compiler support.

Comment: @Allen: Seems to me that compiler support for covariance and contravariance would be useful in this case, just like it would for a richer generics system.  Do you know if anything like this is even on the radar?

Comment: Even if co/contra-variance were added, it would not help global functions. Normal global functions/procedures cannot be generic. Only structural types (class, record, interface) and methods on said types can be generic. A new class static method could be added to TObject do the same thing, but it wouldn't help the existing function.

Comment: @allen Why can global procedures not be generic?

Comment: @Allen et al - yep that was it.  Thanks for jogging the ol' memory banks.  :)

Comment: David, it's already been an SO question (mentioning FreeAndNil, no less): [how to safely bypass Delphi Error: “types of formal and actual parameters must be identical”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051673/how-to-safely-bypass-delphi-error-types-of-formal-and-actual-parameters-must-b). Also, another link for @Deltics, my article from five years ago: [Why must the types of actual and formal var parameters be identical?](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/var-identical)

Comment: @RobKennedy -- That's a great article.

Comment: Note that this `FreeAndNil()` issue has finally been [addressed in Delphi 10.4 Sydney](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/New_features_and_customer_reported_issues_fixed_in_RAD_Studio_10.4). It is no longer possible to pass a non-object variable to `FreeAndNil()`, doing so will cause a compiler error (however, the new implementation allows new kinds of incorrect behavior, but they are much rarer)